Childhood book about a teddy who can't sleep
I am searching for a children's book I read in the late 90s about a teddy bear who sneaks around the bedroom when the boy is away or asleep. He plays with the toy soldier, ballerina and some other toys on the shelf. Then he hears the boy or the mother coming into the room, so he gets back into bed. From what I vaguely remember, the other toys play for a while then get tired and tell him to sleep. I think the story ends with the boy entering the room to sleep and he cuddles the teddy bear. It was definitely a hardback book square and had a greenish border with an illustration on the front. It could be published by Ladybird but I'm not sure.

Okay I've found it. It's called The Teddy Bear Who Couldn't Do Anything by Dina Anastasio, indeed published by Ladybird Books. Hope it helps anyone looking for it.

Though he can't march like the toy soldier, dance like the ballerina, or play the drums like the monkey, the teddy bear discovers that he is able to comfort a sleepy young boy


Please [edit] this answer with a description of how it matches the question. For example, you could include quotes or pictures of the scenes that you mention in the question. This would help people who find the question later, as they could confirm whether the book matches what they remember.

Please come back and accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. As a self-answer, you probably won't be able to complete the process for 48 hours (there's a cool-down period to cut down on potential exploitation of the system), but clicking early will let you know how long you have.
